# Unable to get value of $_.Source using SPE

Tags: powershell-extensions

I have a rich text field in my user defined template and I want to replace the source value of the rich text field. Below is my query where I'm able to read `Name`, `type` etc, however `$_.source` is something which returns nothing though the source value still exists. Any help please.

```ps
$targetTemplate    = Get-Item 'master:/sitecore/templates/User Defined/Common/Data';
$templateFilter    = Get-Item "master:/sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Template Field";

Get-ChildItem $targetTemplate.FullPath -recurse 
| Where-Object { $_.TemplateName -eq $templateFilter.Name -and $_.type -eq 'Rich Text'} 
| ForEach-Object {
    $($_.source)
    #$_.Name
    #$_.Type
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your script in a following way:

```
$targetTemplate    = Get-item 'master:/sitecore/templates/User Defined/Common/Data';
$templateFilter    = Get-Item "master:/sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Template Field";


Get-ChildItem $targetTemplate.FullPath -recurse | Where-Object { $_.TemplateName -eq $templateFilter.Name -and $_.type -eq 'Rich Text'} | ForEach-Object {
    $_._Source # <- Here's the change, added underscore before the Source
    $_.Name
    $_.Type
}
```

Comment: `$_."_Source"` also possible in place of `$_["Source"]`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Why source is different from Name and type.

Comment: Hmmm, can't remember exactly why, but you can do it even simpler: $_._Source. Maybe there is a name conflict or something like that? I have updated my answer.